# Conditional expectation of the square of a random variable

Tags: self-study, conditional-variance

Let the joint PDF of X and Y, $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$ if $x \geq 0$, $|y| < x$, $f(x, y) = 0$ everywhere else. Calculate $\mathbb{V}(Y|X = x)$.

By definition, $\mathbb{V}(Y|X = x) = \mathbb{E}\Big\{\big[Y - \mathbb{E}(Y|X = x)\big]^2|X = x\Big\}$. Earlier, I calculated that $\mathbb{E}(Y|X = x) = 0$, so $\mathbb{V}(Y|X = x) = \mathbb{E}(Y^2|X = x)$.

Could I please have a hint for calculating the conditional expectation of the square of a random variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calculating the (conditional) variance of the square of a random variable, but the (conditional) *expectation* of the square of a random variable.  The left hand side of $$\mathbb{V}(Y|X = x) = \mathbb{E}(Y^2|X = x)$$ is the conditional variance of $Y$, not the conditional **variance** of $Y^2$, and the right side is the conditional *expectation* of $Y^2$, and that's what you are looking for.

Hint: Given the value of $X$ is some $x \geq 0$, first show that the *conditional* distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is $\mathcal U(-x,x)$. Then the calculation of the conditional variance of $Y$ given that $X=x$ is straightforward. Whether you choose to formally write down the proof of what this expectation is, or use a canned formula such as $\dfrac{(b-a)^2}{12} = \dfrac{x^2}{3}$ is up to you.

Comment: Wonderful hint! The conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ is not a function of $y$.

Comment: @johnsmith You are missing the point: the conditional distribution of $Y$, given that $X$ has taken on value $x$ _is_ a function of $y$. Specifically, for $x \geq 0$, $$F_{Y\mid X = x}(y) = \begin{cases}0, &y<-x,\\\frac{y+x}{2x}, & -x \leq y < x,\\1, & y \geq x,\end{cases}$$ from which you can determine the conditional density of $Y$ given that $X=x$ is $$f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2x},& |y| < x,\\0, \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ Although $f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)$ has constant value for $|y|<x$. it is not correct to claim that it is not a function of $y$; it is indeed a function of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

$$\Bbb E[g(Y)|X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{g(y)f_{Y|X}(x,y)\ dy} $$

we need to find the **conditional pdf**, which is:

$$f_{Y|X}(x,y) = {f_{X,Y}(x,y)\over f_X(x)}$$

Now for your specific case, $\Bbb E(Y^2|X)$, first we calculte the **marginal pdf** of $X$ as follow:

$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dy} = \int_{-x}^{x}{{1\over 2}e^{-x}\ dy} = \left.\frac{y}{2}\right|_{-x}^{\ x}e^{-x} = x\ e^{-x}$$

and the **conditional pdf**:

$$ f_{Y|X}(x,y) = {f_{X,Y}(x,y)\over f_X(x)} = {{{1\over 2}e^{-x} \over xe^{-x}} = {1\over 2x}}$$

Now using what we got:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{y^2f_{Y|X}(x,y)\ dy} = \int_{-x}^x{y^2{1\over 2x}\ dy} = \left.{y^3}\right |_{-x}^{\ x} {1\over 6x} = {x^2 \over 3}$$

$$\Bbb E[Y^2|X] = {x^2 \over 3}$$

Comment: That's not the _hint_ that the OP requested; it is the complete solution with all the i's dotted and all the t's crossed.

Comment: @DilipSarwate what do you mean by "i's" and "t's"?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Also, what my answer show is that you dont need the conditional variance.